# Curly brace proof syntax: begin x. = { auto } y. []

Tags: coq

I've seen the following syntax used in Coq proofs, with variations to the relation (`=`) and the tactic (`auto`):

```
begin
  x.
= { auto }
  y.
= { auto }
  z.
[].
```

What's the name of this syntactic construct, and where is it documented?

Comment: Could you please give enough context that the code compiles?

Comment: Sure, here's a longer real-world example: [Lambda.v#L218](https://github.com/pa-ba/reg-machine/blob/3d0bbc55fb271c1e592073440d78417ae8470b29/coq/Lambda.v#L218-L230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a tactic notation defined by [the project you linked](https://github.com/pa-ba/reg-machine). Here is [the file defining the notation](https://github.com/pa-ba/reg-machine/blob/3d0bbc55fb271c1e592073440d78417ae8470b29/coq/Tactics.v), starting at [Line 84](https://github.com/pa-ba/reg-machine/blob/master/coq/Tactics.v#L84).